# Convert Text with date column to display Month and Year in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I am just getting my hands on PowerBI, i am trying to get the date column which is in text to display Month and Year and i am not able to. Any directions. The column type is text which has value like this "2010-09-09T14:46:41+0000" i am trying to display "2010 September".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested the below in Power Query for Excel, but hopefully it should still work for you in Power BI. You could create a simple function like:

```
ParseYearAndMonth = (someText as text) as text => DateTimeZone.ToText(DateTimeZone.From(someText), "yyyy MMMM")
```

(In the function above, we convert the text to type `DateTimeZone`, and then just the `year` and `month` components of the `DateTimeZone` back to text. However, there is no error handling implemented.)

Below is an example of invoking/using the function.

```
let
    someText = "2010-09-09T14:46:41+0000",
    ParseYearAndMonth = (textToParse as text) as text => DateTimeZone.ToText(DateTimeZone.From(textToParse), "yyyy MMMM"),
    someAttempt = ParseYearAndMonth(someText)
in
    someAttempt
```

**Edit:**

Your query might look something like this (although I can't be sure without testing):

```
let
    Source = Facebook.Graph("graph.facebook.com/v2.8/Me/posts"),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"message", "created_time", "id", "story"}),
    ParseYearAndMonth = (someText as text) as text => DateTimeZone.ToText(DateTimeZone.From(someText), "yyyy MMMM"),
    invokedFunction = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "yearAndMonth", each ParseYearAndMonth([created_time]), type text)
in
    invokedFunction
```

Comment: Here is my query editor  \n **********                                                                                  
    let
    Source = Facebook.Graph("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/Me/posts"),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"message", "created_time", "id", "story"}),
  in
    #"Removed Other Columns"  **********  my column is" created_time"  i am not sure where to add your code in there.

Comment: @user388969, have edited my answer if you want to have another look.